# GPS Info Sent to port 5556

Tags: php, gps, netcat

I'm not sure if this is relevant to this site or not, if not I apologize.

I have a GPS device that's transmitting its coordinates to my server on port 5556. I know that its succeeding at doing this because I installed netcat and its monitoring this port, it does return a string.

How can I capture whats returning and utilize it via PHP? I was thinking I could perhaps use AJAX to do a shell_exec netcat and then assign whatever returns to a string, but there are a couple issues with this, specifically it could take up to 60 seconds for a string to return. Am I going about this the wrong way? Perhaps there's tools to listen to 5556 and then return it? Any advice would help Thank you!

Comment: Do you really mean Ajax?

Comment: Well I was going to have a control via a web browser, load an external php file which executes the netcat command on the server and then returns the string to the browser. I've done something similar in the past which executed a command which starting a recording of a video stream and then another command which stopped and saved the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your gps device is supported by [gpsd](http://gpsd.berlios.de/index.html) you're best off setting up that. The source distribution comes with a PHP sample as well, you can see the source at http://git.berlios.de/cgi-bin/cgit.cgi/gpsd/tree/gpsd.php